# If $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ and $\alpha \in BV([a,b])$ is increasing , then $\int_a^bf d\alpha \geq 0.$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, proof-verification, alternative-proof

This is a **proof verification** question. Here, $\, f$ is continuous and $\alpha$ is of bounded variation.

My only tools are the sums, for a given partition $P = \{a=x_0 < \ldots < x_n = b \}$ of $[a,b]$ :
$$S_\alpha(f,P)= \sum_{j=1}^n f(t_j) [\alpha(x_j)-\alpha(x_{j-1})], \,t_j\in[x_{j-1},x_j]$$

and a criterion of integrability:

> If $\alpha \in BV([a,b])$, and $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then there is a **unique** number $I$ such that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that when $P$ is a partition with $\Vert P \Vert<\delta$,
> $$\mid \, S_{\alpha}(f,P)-I\mid \,<\epsilon.$$

**My proof:** Since $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ and $\alpha$ is increasing, we have that $S_{\alpha}(f,P)\geq 0$ for any partition $P$.

Let $\epsilon >0$, then there is a $\delta >0$ such that if $\Vert P \Vert<\delta$, $\, \mid S_{\alpha}(f,P)-I\mid \,<\epsilon.$

Now **assume** $I<0$. Then $-I >0$, and so
$$\epsilon > \,\mid S_{\alpha}(f,P)-I \mid \, > \,\mid S_{\alpha}(f,P)-0 \mid \geq 0,$$

so $I$ is not unique! Hence $\int_a^bf d\alpha = I \geq0.$

> Is this proof correct?
>
> Using only this facts, is there a direct proof?

Comment: @Nobody yes, but in my book there is no definition of lower and upper sums so I was wondering if it was possible to prove it without using those concepts.

Comment: Your proof is correct, only that when you say $-I > 0$ implies $|S_\alpha(f, P) - I | > |S_\alpha (f,P)-0|$, you need to use that $S_\alpha (f, P) \ge 0$.

Comment: @LuisVera Yes, that was my mistake!